# How do I make D3js script responsive to window size?

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I am trying to make this example in D3js,
http://bl.ocks.org/nsonnad/4481531

but I would like to make the graph responsive to window size. How would I do that? 
I tried searching online and it looks like making the svg responsive seem to be the solution, but I can't seem to implement it to make it work. Would someone please help?

Comment: It sounds like you found the solution but can't get the code working. If you posted some example code, we might be able to help.

Comment: If, by "responsive," you really mean to make the size of the graph vary according to browser window size, you could add a `viewBox` attribute to the `<svg>` element and then use JavaScript or CSS to set the size of the containing `<div>`. Of course, "responsive" design is much more than simply resizing elements, so perhaps you mean something more involved. In that case, you'll need to spell out the desired behavior.

Comment: Try this post: http://www.brendansudol.com/posts/responsive-d3/